# How can I adjust this PHP table lay out?

Tags: php

I use this code on another page1 and it works for that page but the SQL Select for page1 returns one row at a time from one SQL table.  This works but I would like to adjust the layout but I do not know how to get what is needed.

```
$isql = "Select AO.OrderNumber, AO.Name, AO.Address, AO.OrderDate, AOP.PartNumber, AOP.PartDescription
From tblAceOrders AO
Left outer join tblAceOrdersParts AOP on AOP.OrderNumber=AO.OrderNumber
Where AO.OrderDate between '01/01/2018' and '01/15/2018'"
;

 $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $isql);

if( $stmt === false ) {
     {
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
        }
    }}}


/**
 * Put resules in a table
 */
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $isql, array(), array("Scrollable" => 'static'));
if( $stmt === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);  
if ($row_count === false) { 
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_num_rows)";
    exit;
}

// Set the number of rows to be returned on a page. 
$rowsPerPage = 10;

// Get the total number of rows returned by the query.  
$rowsReturned = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt); 
if($rowsReturned === false) 
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
elseif($rowsReturned == 0) 
{ 
    echo "No rows returned."; 
//    exit(); 
} 
else 
{     
    /* Calculate number of pages. */ 
    $numOfPages = ceil($rowsReturned/$rowsPerPage); 
}

    echo "<table id='table_id'' border='5' column width='100%'><tr><th><center>Order Number</center></th><th><center>Name</center></th><th><center>Address</center></th>
    <th><center>Order Date</center></th><th><center>Part Number</center></th><th><center>Part Description</center></th></th></></tr>";


while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 

{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['OrderNumber']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['Name']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['Address']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['OrderDate']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['PartNumber']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['PartDescription']."</center></td>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Produces:

```
OrderNumber     Name            Address                     OrderDate       Partnumber      PartDescription
2018-001        Mike Smith      435 W 8th St, Trussville    01/02/2018      C-524           Left Panel
2018-001        Mike Smith      435 W 8th St, Trussville    01/02/2018      MD-5632         Rear Patch
2018-001        Mike  Smith     435 W 8th St, Trussville    01/02/2018      J-7C5           Left Panel Bottom
2018-002        Chris Dixon     8 N Elm St, Trussville      01/07/2018      HH-5225         Outside Door
2018-003        Brian Sinclar   772 Derwood Ave, Birmingham 01/07/2018      T4-213          Bottom Lug/Outside
2018-003        Brian Sinclar   772 Derwood Ave, Birmingham 01/07/2018      D-5398          Bottom Bolt/Inside
```

But I would like it to output something close to this:

```
OrderNumber     Name            Address                     OrderDate       Partnumber      PartDescription
2018-001        Mike Smith      435 W 8th St, Trussville    01/02/2018      C-524           Left Panel
                                                                            MD-5632         Rear Patch
                                                                            J-7C5           Left Panel Bottom

2018-002        Chris Dixon     8 N Elm St, Trussville      01/07/2018      HH-5225         Outside Door

2018-003        Brian Sinclar   772 Derwood Ave, Birmingham 01/07/2018      T4-213          Bottom Lug/Outside
                                                                            D-5398          Bottom Bolt/Inside
```

or (preferably)

```
OrderNumber     Name            Address                     OrderDate       
2018-001        Mike Smith      435 W 8th St, Trussville    01/02/2018  
Partnumber      PartDescription                                             
C-524           Left Panel
MD-5632         Rear Patch
J-7C5           Left Panel Bottom                                                           

OrderNumber     Name            Address                     OrderDate
2018-002        Chris Dixon     8 N Elm St, Trussville      01/07/2018
Partnumber      PartDescription 
HH-5225         Outside Door

OrderNumber     Name            Address                     OrderDate
2018-003        Brian Sinclar   772 Derwood Ave, Birmingham 01/07/2018      
Partnumber      PartDescription
T4-213          Bottom Lug/Outside
D-5398          Bottom Bolt/Inside
```

My thoughts are to put each row in a seperate table but I do not know how to implement this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're new to PHP, do yourself a favour and don't `echo` out HTML. It gets messy fast, is terrible to work with, and there are far better alternatives (Twig, Blade, Plates, PHP in HTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the order number in a variable. When processing each row, check if the current order number is the same as the variable. If it is, leave the first 4 fields of the row blank.

```
$prev_order = null;
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    if ($row['OrderNumber'] == $prev_order) {
        echo "<td colspan='4'></td>"; // Leave first 4 columns blank since they're the same
    } else {
        echo "<td><center>" . $row['OrderNumber']."</center></td>";
        echo "<td><center>" . $row['Name']."</center></td>";
        echo "<td><center>" . $row['Address']."</center></td>";
        echo "<td><center>" . $row['OrderDate']."</center></td>";
        $prev_order = $row['OrderNumber'];
    }
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['PartNumber']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['PartDescription']."</center></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

You should also have `ORDER BY AO.OrderNumber` at the end of the query, otherwise it won't necessarily put all the rows for the same order together.

To get the second format, you need to move the column headings into the loop, and display the column headings followed by the one row for the order whenever the order number changes.

```
$prev_order = null;
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    if ($row['OrderNumber'] != $prev_order) {
        echo "<th><center>Order Number</center></th><th><center>Name</center></th><th><center>Address</center></th>
<th><center>Order Date</center></th>";
        echo "<td><center>" . $row['OrderNumber']."</center></td>";
        echo "<td><center>" . $row['Name']."</center></td>";
        echo "<td><center>" . $row['Address']."</center></td>";
        echo "<td><center>" . $row['OrderDate']."</center></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr><th><center>Part Number</center></th><th><center>Part Description</center></th></th></></tr>";
        $prev_order = $row['OrderNumber'];
    }
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['PartNumber']."</center></td>";
    echo "<td><center>" . $row['PartDescription']."</center></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. Works as requested with your code and I learned some things. After putting it in place my columns are very tiny and will not all display, as I suspected when printed. Any way to display each record as a table so that it wraps? Thank you again for the code.

Comment: I added the second version.

Comment: I'm not sure why the columns are tiny. Normally they automatically adjust based on the width of the biggest cell, but sometimes cells will be wrapped so that the table fits on the screen. You can use CSS to set column widths and prevent word wrapping (e.g. the `white-space: pre;` style).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for the help. Made a few adjustments and works like a charm.